# Show that every element of the group can be written in the form of $e,i,j,k,m...$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In Serge Lang's Algebra Chapter II Session I Question 9, there is a question:

There exists a group of order 8 having generators denoted by $i,j,k$ such that

1. $ij=k$,
2. $jk=i$,
3. $ki=j$,
4. $i^2=j^2=k^2$

also denote $i^2$ by $m$.

Now prove that the entire group is $\{e,i,j,k,m,mi,mj,mk\}$

I don't know where to start. I have tried starting from the definition of generator in which each element is written as a product of $i,j,k$. However, I can't extend further.

I have also tried to research on other math stack post. Most of them, however, have a different structure instead of the one above.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: First work out what the inverses of $i, j, k, m$ are. Then the group elements are all products of sequences of these. You should be able to reduce each one to something in your set.

Comment: For help you can also search for quaternion group.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to start by proving that $m^2=e$, which is not completely obvious. But note that $i^2=j^2=k^2=m$ implies that $m$ is in the centre of the group.

So we have
$$k=ij=ji^{-1} \Rightarrow j^{-1}ij=i^{-1} \Rightarrow j^{-1}i^2j = i^{-2} \Rightarrow i^2=i^{-2} \Rightarrow m^2=e.$$

Now let $S = \{e,i,j,k,m,mi,mj,mk\}$ and $X=\{i,j,k\}$ and use the relations to show that $sx \in S$ for all $s \in S$ and $x \in X$, which proves the result.

Comment: I don't understand the first step $ij=ji^{-1}$, the inverse of $ji^{-1}$ is $ij^{-1}$ and when multiplied into $ij$ it is $i^2$. Besides, for the third step, $j^{-1}i^2j$, I see how this equate $i^2$ but I can't see why is it $i^{-2}$

Comment: $ij$ and $ji^{-1}$ are both equal to $k$. I said in my answer that $m$ commutes with all generators, so $j^{-1}i^2j = i^2$.

Comment: I think, $k=ij\rightarrow ki=j\rightarrow iji=j\rightarrow ijii^{-1}=ji^{-1}\rightarrow ij=ji^{-1}$

Comment: Besides, $ij=ji^{-1}\rightarrow j^{-1}ij=i^{-1}\rightarrow i^{-2}=j^{-1}iji^{-1}=j^{-1}iij=j^{-1}i^2j=j^{-1}j^2j=j^2=i^2$